# converting Gmail to PDF: embedded images in HTML

Tags: python, gmail-api, mime

I am using the Gmail API to download e-mails. When these e-mails are HTML, I try to convert them to PDF using Python's pdfkit.

This works in many cases but in some cases the html payload contains image tags like `src=“cid:169abdc4ae2c4da871d2”`.

It seems that this "cid" tag refers to an image sent as part of the multipart e-mail, but this cannot be processed by PDFkit. Error is:

```
wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Loading pages (1/6)
Error: Failed to load cid:169abf0d0cdfffb7aff2, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "cid" is unknown
```

How can I solve this? Is there a way to convert this HTML I get from the gmail payload to standard HTML with proper picture sources?

Comment: Try the steps here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130360/python-download-as-pdf-all-emails-from-a-label-gmail

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53658868/5022913). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use "remove_tags" method in the [w3lib Package](https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.html.remove_tags):

Remove all tags:

```
import w3lib.html
doc = '<div><p><b>This is a link:</b> <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a></p></div>'
w3lib.html.remove_tags(doc)
'This is a link: example'
```

Remove specific tags:

```
 w3lib.html.remove_tags(doc, which_ones=('a','b'))
'<div><p>This is a link: example</p></div>'
```